# Optimizing a piece of code that generates every possible word with a given length

Tags: python

I wrote a program to generate every possible word with a certain amount of letters, and write it all to a file. However, I am not exactly the best at optimizing code and the program crashes and kills itself when I attempt to make one with a length of seven. This is annoying as I was hoping to be able to run the program over multiple hours/days to generate words with 10 or even more characters.
I still don't know really all that much about python and I've never had a program outright crash the python shell before, so I really don't know what to do. Is there any way to make this program run words with greater lengths, or maybe even slow it down or split up the lists to make it stop crashing?
Thanks a bunch!

Code:

```
import string
import datetime

begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()

maxLen = int(input("Max Length:   "))
baseAlpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

print()

for i in range(maxLen-1) :
    for i,v in enumerate(alphabet) :
        alphabet[i] = [v]*26

    for indexPerList,listValue in enumerate(alphabet) :
        for indexInsideList,listIndexValue in enumerate(listValue) :
            alphabet[indexPerList][indexInsideList] += baseAlpha[indexInsideList]
    tempListAlphabet = []
    for i in alphabet :
        for j in i :
            tempListAlphabet.append(j)
    alphabet = tempListAlphabet

print(len(alphabet))
print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

f = open("output.txt","a")
for i in alphabet :
    f.write(i + ' ')
f.close()
```

Comment: Did you estimate the number of words of 10 characters? Using only 26 letters, it's 26**10, so about 1.4 * 10^15, which would occupy about 14000 TB. Where would you expect to store that?

Comment: "... and the program crashes and kills itself" - please provide the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate all the output in memory and write it at the end. Write each item as soon as you have generated it.